# How do you do a join in LinqToSQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I have a data setup of the following form: `State` 1->n `County` 1->n `City`.

Within my State object, I want to return all counties that contain at least one city with a population greater than `p`.  Were I to write this in sql it would be:

```
select distinct co.*
from County co join City ci on ci.CountyID = co.ID
where ci.Population > @p
and co.StateCode = @StateCode
```

Maybe the sql could be optimized better (and I'll certainly appreciate pointers there), but that's not the point...

Anyway, I want to do this in Linq, in the State class.  My code (obviously not compiling) now looks like this:

```
var q = 
  from co in Counties
  where co.Cities // uh-oh, now what?
```

How do you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have association properties...

```
var q =  from co in Counties
         where co.Cities.Any(city =>city.Population > p)
         select co;
```

Or simply:

```
var q = Counties.Where(co => co.Cities.Any(city => city.Population > p));
```

Comment: Marc, you are the wind beneath my wings.  :)

Comment: Man I love Lambda's :) Very elegant solution